# Cannot move tab-bar to buttom of android with the meteor package meteoric

Tags: android, meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

So im trying to use the meteoric package, that combines meteor with the ionic framework. and the following code:

```
    {{#ionTabs style="ios" class="tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Tab1" path="login" icon="android-home"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Tab2" path="home" icon="android-star"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Tab3" path="notifications" icon="heart"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Tab4" path="calendar" icon="gear-b"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Tab5" path="settings" icon="gear-b"}}
  {{/ionTabs}}
```

puts it in the buttom, while

```
      {{#ionTabs style="android" class="tabs-background-positive tabs-color- light"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Tab1" path="login" icon="android-home"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Tab2" path="home" icon="android-star"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Tab3" path="notifications" icon="heart"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Tab4" path="calendar" icon="gear-b"}}
        {{> ionTab title="Tab5" path="settings" icon="gear-b"}}
  {{/ionTabs}}
```

puts it in the top.   ive tried the following:

```
 Template.main.rendered = function () {
        $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom'); //other values: top
  };
```

To set settings, but obviously $ionicConfigProvider is undefined,
so i guess my question is, how do i set ionics config settings from meteor?, i only found examples of setting the config with angular.

I suppose that i can use the ios style, for my android app, but thats 
not really a valid solution in my case.

Btw. ive tried to run it on a live android-device aswell, and its the same result, as in the browser.

I allso tried to run the demos from the site, on my own mobile-device, with the exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution. I'm using Meteor/angular/ionic so it may not be what you're looking for, but I'll show you what I've got in case it helps.

In my routes.js file I added the `$ionicConfigProvider` argument and line in the config function:

```
...

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {


    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom'); // other values: top


... //rest of config function
```

This may be particularly angular but it got my tabs showing on the bottom of both iOS and Android devices.